# Databricks Regex (Java patterns)

Tags: regex, databricks

TLDR: I want to extract schema.table_name from a sentence where those are the only word.word matches

I'm looking at parsing some logs with Databricks regex_extract (Java regular expression).
The format is something like this:

`2022.11.07T00:00:00.0000 | log_info schema.table_name... [ hh.mm.ss ]`

I started with this to get just what I needed to extract from:

```
SELECT split_part(split_part(message, '|', 2), '[', 1)
FROM (SELECT '2022.11.07T00:00:00.0000 | log_info schema.table_name... [ hh.mm.ss ]' as message)
```

Which gets me: "log_info schema.table_name..."

But now I want to get the first word before and after the first period.

Any help would be great, especially if there is an even more elegant solution than using the split_parts.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in a dream last night.

```
SELECT regexp_extract(message, '([a-z]+[\.][a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+)*)')
FROM (SELECT '2022.11.07T00:00:00.0000 | log_info schema.table_name... [ hh.mm.ss ]' as message)
```